# Generate QName for a java class using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to write a routine that given java.lang.Class as input would return the right QName for it. Does JAXB expose any hooks that we can make use of? I tried using JAXBIntrospector but that fails to generate QNames for primitive types and their wrappers.

Comment: What is "the right QName for java.lang.Class"? can you please clarify?

Comment: I think he wants to get "xsd:string" for java.lang.String etc.

Comment: (some year later...) he want's a QName constant in every generated jaxb dto which he then can map to his custom jaxb dto class type.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716631/jaxb-make-qname-in-objectfactory-accessible